# Unit Test Angular Router Event NavigationEnd

Tags: angular

I'm trying to unit test my app.component.ts which listens for router events and sets the page title. I'm able to test if getTitle function has been called, but I'm really hung up on testing the remaining parts. (I need 100% line coverage). Maybe you can help.

My **app.component.ts** looks like that (just the relevant parts):

```
export class AppComponent {
  public title = '';

constructor(private router: Router, private titleService: Title) {

    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.title = this.getTitle(this.router.routerState, this.router.routerState.root).join('-');
        this.titleService.setTitle(this.title);
      }
    });
  }

  // collect title data properties from all child routes
  public getTitle(state: any, parent: any) {
    const data: any = [];
    if (parent && parent.snapshot.data && parent.snapshot.data.title) {
      data.push(parent.snapshot.data.title);
    }
    if (state && parent) {
      data.push(... this.getTitle(state, state.firstChild(parent)));
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

And my current **app.component.spec.ts** like that:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let methodSpy: jasmine.Spy;
  let titleService: Title;

  const eventSubject = new ReplaySubject<RouterEvent>(1);

  const routerMock = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate'),
    events: eventSubject.asObservable(),
    url: 'container'
  }

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      providers: [
        AppComponent,
        { provide: Router, useValue: routerMock},
        { provide: Title}
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    methodSpy = spyOn(component, 'getTitle');
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  // this works
  it('getTitle should have been called', () => {
    eventSubject.next(new NavigationEnd(1, 'container', 'container'));
    expect(methodSpy).toHaveBeenCalled;
  });

  // this gives me a "cannot read property root of undefined" error
  it('page title should be "Container"', () => {
    titleService = TestBed.get(Title);
    expect(titleService.getTitle()).toBe("Container");
  });
});
```

I also tried something like this, but still no luck:

```
it('page title should be "Container"', () => {
  expect(component.title).toEqual("Container");
});
```

Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

Your stub should contain more props :

```
  const routerMock = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate'),
    events: eventSubject.asObservable(),
    url: 'container',
    routerState : { root: { snapshot: { data: { title: 'my stub value' } } } }
  }
```

Comment: This still gives ma a "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" error.

Comment: @Manuela I thought you got it ... Nevermind. I have updated my answer with the full stub.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped a bit, but now I'm still getting an error "Cannot read property 'join' of undefined". Looks like my getTitle function doesn't return anything. Maybe this is caused by some async issues. I tried "fakeAsync" and "tick()" but I think I am missing something here.

Comment: @Manuela you're supposed to mock it.